# How to use map functions while iterating a list in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I have list of maps with few color properties. I would like to create one class for each map using the color properties they hold. I was using the docs from [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/dynamically-create-css-classes-sass), [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/) and [here](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method).

I have come up with the below code so far (It is a `.scss` file).

```
$blue: (
  base: #6ac0e2,
  center: #38B5EA,
  shadow: #316980
);

$green: (
  base: #B0BF1A,
  center: #B3BA5D,
  shadow: #316980
);

$bloom_list: $blue, $green;

@each $color in map-keys($bloom_list) {
  .bloom-with-#{$color} {
    @include bloom-background(map-get($color, 'base'), map-get($color, 'center'), map-get($color, 'shadow'));
  }
}

@mixin bloom-background($base_color, $radial_color, $shadow-color) {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px $shadow-color;
  background-color: $base_color;
  @include filter-gradient($base_color, $radial_color, horizontal); // IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient
  @include background-image(radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, $base_color 0%, $radial_color 100%));
}
```

But I get a SASS syntax error,

```
Invalid CSS after "  base": expected ")", was ": #6ac0e2,"
```

What is the right way to get the value inside a map while iterating using its key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$colourList: (
    green  : (
      base: #6ac0e2, 
      center: #38B5EA, 
      shadow: #316980
    ),

    blue: (
     base: #6ac0e2,
     center: #38B5EA,
     shadow: #316980
   )
);

@mixin bloom-background($base_color, $radial_color, $shadow-color) {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px $shadow-color;
  background-color: $base_color;
  @include background-image(radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, $base_color 0%, $radial_color 100%));
}
@each $key, $color in $colourList {
  .bloom-with-#{$key} {
     @include bloom-background(map-get($color, 'base'), map-get($color, 'center'), map-get($color, 'shadow'));
  }
}
```

Been tested and working with sass(3.4.7 & 3.4.4) compass(1.0.1)

Comment: Now the error is `Invalid CSS after "        green ": expected ")", was ": ("`. I think the issue is that, SASS is not reading the indented multi line input.

Comment: @emaillenin it's been tested with sass compiler 3.4.7, have a look here: http://sassmeister.com/gist/56eb0c381c7fa45c3abe

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am locked with SASS 3.2 due to activeadmin gem.